# tracking and avoiding obstacle by LASER

Tags: ros, hokuyo-laser

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do anyone use LASER in gazebo to simulate tracking robot and avoiding obstacle at the same time? could you please suggest about the algorithm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147996/tracking-and-avoiding-obstacle-by-laser/) by [bestbesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/13411/bestbesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend segbot package to you. Segbot package includes both hokuyo laser and kinect. I think that It is useful for you. At first, you will try next command on terminal and check packages.

```
apt-cache search ros-hydro-segbot
```

If you use distribution except for hydro, you please change a part of hydro into your distribution.
In case of hydro, you will find 8 packages.

```
ros-hydro-segbot
ros-hydro-segbot-apps
ros-hydro-segbot-bringup
ros-hydro-segbot-description
ros-hydro-segbot-gazebo
ros-hydro-segbot-navigation
ros-hydro-segbot-sensors
ros-hydro-segbot-simulator
```

After installing them, you will launch segbot with next command.

```
roslaunch segbot_gazebo segbot_navigation.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1